# C#: How do I raise a child event immediately before the parent event finish executing?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm leveraging on a third-party's API to control their hardware. Their methods will never return a value but will only trigger events that will return values that were changed or exceptions occurred while changing the values. I guess it is like UI events.

Let's say there is an event handler `button_Click()` that I also use to call a function `ThirdPartyAPI.SetSomeStuffConfig(some parameters...)` besides other functions. After calling that 3rd party function, I need to immediately access the values or exceptions that are only accessible through that function event's event handler. Problem is, the event raised by 3rd party function will only execute after `button_Click()` has finished.

Is there any solution or coding pattern that I can use to workaround this? Is it possible to trigger and run the third party's event/event handler before the `button_Click()`'s event handler has finished executing?

I.e., I would like to access the values and exceptions immediately after calling the third party function in `button_Click()`.

**Tried solution**

What I have tried is breaking `button_Click()` into two parts. The parts that occur after calling `ThirdPartyAPI.SetSomeStuffConfig(some parameters...)` will be put into the 3rd party's event handler. However, this is very troublesome and restrictive.

**Sample code of third party's API**

```
public void Stuff_SetConfig(int id, int mode, string Exception)
{

   //returns the new ID, Mode and exception if unable to set ID or Mode on the hardware
    this.ID = id;
    this.Mode = mode;
}

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThirdParty.Stuff newStuff = new ThirdParty.Stuff();
    newStuff.StuffSetConfig += new ThirdParty.IThirdPartyStuffEvents_StuffSetConfigEventHandler(Stuff_SetConfig);
    //call some functions...

    newStuff.SetConfig(5, 10); //triggers StuffSetConfigEventHandler
    //call other functions...
    Console.WriteLine("ID is " + this.ID + " and this.Mode is " + this.Mode); //ID and Mode is empty because the Stuff_SetConfig event handler has not yet run.
}
```

Comment: Can you share any code sample?

Comment: If the class that exposes the event does not expose a way for you to trigger the event (which I dare say it shouldn't do anyway), then no, there is no *correct* way to fire that event. From what I understand it is not enough for you to just run the event handler you have hooked up, you also need data from the class that exposed the event, in which case the first sentence of this comment stands.

Comment: @Progressive I have added a code sample. Hopefully it will provide some insight to all.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen there is a class but as strange as it sounds, in order to access some properties .e.g, `object.GetConfig()`, the class's method returns nothing but only triggers an event. I'm not sure the rationale behind designing a class like this but I think Damien is onto something.

Comment: This is a pretty common requirement, usually solved by moving the common code into another method so you also call it yourself.  Also the best way to arrive at the correct code, it is pretty unlikely that you really meant to create a new Stuff object over and over again.  The constructor of the form class tends to be the right place to create the object.

Comment: @HansPassant I see... btw, you are correct. The new Stuff object isn't supposed to be created again and again. I was just writing up a quick example and didn't check thoroughly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Contingent on the API you're wrapping being similar to EAP).

In the [Event-based Async Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/event-based-asynchronous-pattern-overview) (EAP), you call an async method and expect events to be raised when the work is completed - whether successfully or unsuccessfully. It's an older pattern for authoring async code in .NET. When Microsoft introduced `Task`, and especially after they added `async` and `await` to the language, there was a lot of interest in adapting the older patterns to make them look like the modern `Task`-returning methods of the [Task-based Async Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap) (TAP).

Unfortunately, transforming EAP isn't as straightforward as adapting the older APM (.NET's original async pattern). However, they do provide [guidance on doing so](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types#tasks-and-the-event-based-asynchronous-pattern-eap). Their example is the older [`WebClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) class with a `DownloadFileAsync` method and `DownloadFileCompleted` event. Here's their adaptation:

> ```
> public static Task<string> DownloadStringAsync(Uri url)
>  {
>      var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
>      var wc = new WebClient();
>      wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (s,e) =>
>          {
>              if (e.Error != null) 
>                 tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
>              else if (e.Cancelled) 
>                 tcs.TrySetCanceled();
>              else 
>                 tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result);
>          };
>      wc.DownloadStringAsync(url);
>      return tcs.Task;
> }
> ```

So, if you can do something similar with the third party API, you can create wrappers and pretend that their methods are `Task` returning instead. And once you've got that, you can maybe `await` that `Task` in the middle of your `button_click` handler.

---

Doing it all in one method, we can abuse captures to smuggle the multiple results out, but I'd recommend putting the `TaskCompletionSource` stuff into a separate method as above and deal with the multiple results in a different way (C# 7 tuples?):

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThirdParty.Stuff newStuff = new ThirdParty.Stuff();

    //call some functions...

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    int mode;
    newStuff.SetConfig += (_id, _mode, ex) =>
    {
       if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(ex))
       {
          tcs.TrySetException(new Exception(ex));
       }
       else
       {
          mode = _mode;
          tcs.TrySetResult(_id);
       }
    }
    newStuff.SetConfig(5, 10);
    //call other functions...
    var id = await tcs.Task;
    Console.WriteLine("ID is " + id + " and this.Mode is " + mode);
}
```

Comment: Seems viable. I'll look into that. Btw, I have updated the question with sample code.

Comment: @Mark - I've had a stab at a cheeky adaptation.

Comment: Very cheeky (I mean nice!) indeed. Gonna try it out asap.